# How do you update the SDK version?

Tags: flutter

Because alrakeeniot requires SDK version >=2.19.6 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed

Answer (score 0):

Update it in the **pubspec.yaml** file. It is located in the root folder of the project

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: ">=2.19.6 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: ">=2.19.6 <3.0.0"
```

After updating the `pubspec.yaml` file, run the following command in your terminal to update your project dependencies: `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the SDK version in `pubspec.yaml` file then `pub get` again.